# Pytorch Normalize() receiving torch.float32 tensor but recognising it as torch.int32

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, normalization, standardization

I'm trying to normalize the NYU v2 Depth Dataset, and this is the transform I'm applying to each image coming through:

```
def standard_transform(normalise=False):
    composition = [
        transforms.Resize(standard_img_HW()),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
    ]
    if normalise:
        composition.append(transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)))
    return transforms.Compose(composition)
```

But it throws a runtime error of

```
TypeError(f"Input tensor should be a float tensor. Got {tensor.dtype}.")
TypeError: Input tensor should be a float tensor. Got torch.int32.
```

Now, I'd be happy to solve it if the tensors were indeed int dtypes, but the depth maps that are coming through are float32 tensors.

```
tensor([[[2.7520, 2.7520, 2.7522,  ..., 2.2429, 2.2428, 2.2428],
         [2.7519, 2.7520, 2.7521,  ..., 2.2429, 2.2428, 2.2427],
         [2.7518, 2.7518, 2.7520,  ..., 2.2428, 2.2427, 2.2427],
         ...,
         [2.1980, 2.1980, 2.1979,  ..., 2.0813, 2.0810, 2.0809],
         [2.1979, 2.1979, 2.1977,  ..., 2.0816, 2.0813, 2.0812],
         [2.1979, 2.1978, 2.1977,  ..., 2.0817, 2.0814, 2.0813]]])
torch.Size([1, 480, 640])
torch.float32
```

How should I go about solving this?

I've gone in circles making sure that the tensors are indeed tensors and not images, via ToTensor(), and also double checking that the tensors that I wish to normalise are indeed float tensors.